# Significance of ROW KEY in a database table

Tags: database, primary-key, rows

I was trying to find out the difference between a primary key and a ROWKEY. I was able to understand that the primary key is unique for each row, but my research on ROWKEY also intend to give a similar meaning.

Could anyone please give some brief idea about the significance of a row key in database table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Primary key is the declared identifier for a row in a table, when the developer designs the table. In each row, the value of the primary key column must be unique among all rows in the table.
- Row key (also known as row ID) is an internal database identifier for the row. It may only be valid for a short period of time, e.g. the current transaction. The reason for this is that the database may move the row on the disk, an operation which wouldn't be visible if you referred to the row by primary key, but might cause errors if you referred to it by row key, which would have changed due to the change of location.
- Parent key is another word for foreign key. It is a reference to a primary key in another table.

Example: an Orders table and a Customer table.

```
create table orders(order_id varchar2(253), order_customer_id number);
create table customers(customer_id number, name varchar2(255));
```

The primary key of `orders` is `order_id`. The primary key of `customers` is `customer_id`. `order_customer_id` is a parent key, or in other words a foreign key, which refers to the primary key of the `customer` table. Row keys are not defined explicitly - they are provided by the database automatically.

Let me know if you still don't grasp it.

Comment: Do you mean to say that the row key is just a temporary key and changes from time to time. According to my logical understanding, if I have to insert a row then it is an efficient way to perform append opeartions rather than inserting a row in between. So in which cases the databse may move the row in the disk?? when are these row keys helpful? If my question is not clear enough please let me know.

Comment: Yes, it is just a temporary key, at least in Oracle. No, in a relational database the database chooses where to insert the row, not you. You have no control over where the row is stored within the table. If you need the data back in a specific order you use `ORDER BY` in your SQL queries. To do efficient inserts of multiple rows you can do a bulk insert, but that does not specify row keys, that is just a fast way to transmit data to the DBMS.

Comment: For example : I have 10 records in a table with primary key assigned, then all the 10 rows have row key assigned automatically by the database. In case if I insert a new row, then the row keys might change if the row inserted in random. But the primary keys remain same. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.